# Shortcut to copy selected text horizontaly in VisualStudioCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I don't know if this exists but I would like to have the equivalent of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>|<kbd>Down</kbd> which duplicates the line up or down, but horizontally with the text selected.

For example, let's consider this program:

```py
print("Hello world")
```

If the selected text is `Hello world` and I do the shortcut it will give something like:

```py
print("Hello worldHello world")
```

Basically, it would ideally be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>|<kbd>Left</kbd> but this shortcut doesn't do that.

Comment: select it and just do a normal ctrl+c  then paste it n times of ctrl +v ?

Comment: Well, you can do that, but it's way slower. Like you can also just use Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V instead of [Shift+Alt+Up|Down] but I would like to know if there is a faster way to do it

Comment: You want the original selection to be selected after the insertion?  This can be done.

Comment: @Mark yes if its possible ! So its possible to do Shift+Alt+Left|Right ten  times in a row for example

Comment: After thinking of it a lot, vim is just better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do the paste to the right repeatedly.  You will need this extension which I wrote [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview):

Make this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+right",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "cursorRight",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      "cursorHome"  // return cursor to beginning of line
    ],
    "find": "${CLIPBOARD}",
    "restrictFind": "once"  // refind the clipboard text, use only the first find match
  }
},

{
  "key": "shift+alt+left",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "cursorLeft",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      "cursorHome"
    ],
    "find": "${CLIPBOARD}",
    "restrictFind": "once"
  }
}
```

First, select what you want to repeat to the right.  Second, trigger either keybinding.

It works by doing a `find` for the clipboard content (and automatically selecting it) each time after the paste.

The only caveat is it won't work if you have the exact same text as the selected text earlier on the same line.

- Actually, there is no need for both commands as they produce the same indistinguishable result.

Answer (score 0):

use extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Define the following key bindings

```json
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+left",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
            "cursorLeft",
            "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
        ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+right",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
            "cursorRight",
            "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
        ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to keep the select text selected? Because when I'm doing Shift+Alt+right|left it unselect it